# Optional parameters in url - Slim 3

Tags: php, rest, slim-3

I have a pretty straightforward question. I am using Slim 3 to build a RESTfull api.

How come this works:

```
$app->get('/news[/{params:.*}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));
    $response->write("news!");
    return $response;

});
```

But not this:

```
$app->get('/news[/{params:.*}]/details', function ($request, $response, $args) {
$params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));
        $response->write("news details");
        return $response;

});
```

In fact the latter does not compile.

Comment: Can you add an example of the path you would like to route?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using **unlimited** [Optional segments](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#optional-segments), implies that each consequent segment is reserved.

In your defined route for `/news[/{params:.*}]` the following paths qualify:

```
/news
/news/foo
/news/foo/bar
/news/foo/bar/...
```

So adding an extra fixed segment `/details` won't work if you add it after the square brackets.

When you define it as `/news[/{params:.*}/details]` with the `/details` segment within the square brackets it does work for details, but not in combination with the first route & will break. You can still go with your first route & check the last param, or with an optional param within:

```
$app->get('/news[/{params:.*}[/details]]', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));

    if (end($params) != 'details') {

        $response->write("news!");

    } else {

        // $params for details;
        array_pop($params);

        $response->write("news details");
    }

    // $params is an array of all the optional segments
    var_dump($params);

});
```

**Update:**

The actual problem here seems like a colliding definition in the routes, where for example the unlimited optional segments would always match the second defined route. It can be solved by defining the routes with a **route regex** & enclosing them in a **route group** prior to non-colliding matches:

```
$app->group('/news', function () {

    $this->map(['GET'], '', function ($request, $response, $args) {

        $response->write("news w/o params");

    })->setName('news');

    // Unlimited optional parameters not ending with "/details"
    $this->get('/{params:[[:alnum:]\/]*[^\/details]}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        $params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));

        var_dump($params);

        $response->write("news!");
    });

    // Unlimited optional parameters ending with "/details"
    $this->get('/{params:[[:alnum:]\/]*\/details}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        $params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));
        array_pop($params); // fix $params

        var_dump($params);

        $response->write("news details");
    });

});
```

Comment: I need something to differentiate between /news[/{params:.*}]/details and /news[/{params:.*}]. I can always write it as /news/details[/{params:.*}] but it wont be self explanatory anymore...

Comment: I see, I have updated the answer but actually your first route does comply for both routes since a last segment as "/details" does match your first route as well.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: I just updated the answer again. It may be closer to what you wish to achieve.

Comment: I will try a verson of this but I'll give it to you. It is not exactly want I want but it is a good hint.