# Slim 3 Configure specific regex into route

Tags: php, regex, string, slim

I have a regex: `^(profile\/\~)(:\([0-9a-z,-]+\))?$` this allows strings like: `profile/~` or `profile/~:(var1,var2,var3,...)`

I need to configure this regex into a Slim route for accept the following routes.

```
http://example.com/v1/profile/~:(var1, var2)
http://example.com/v1/profile/~:
```

My PHP code:

```
$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->group('/v1', function () {
    $this->get('/profile/~[:[{fields:[0-9a-z,-]+}]]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
        $response->getBody()->write("Hello " . $args['fields']);
        return $response;
    })->setName('profile');
});
$app->run();
```

Is there any way to convert that regex to one compatible with slim?

Comment: So are we saying you need to restrict the trailing substring pattern to `no parenthetical` and `2 vars in the parenthetical`?

Comment: Hello, @mickmackusa i need to accept the parenthetical into the Slim Route.

Comment: Consider some of the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432694/optional-parameters-in-url-slim-3  (I don't use Slim)  If you solve your issue, please post your own answer with as much explanation as you can so that future readers can benefit from your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a little bit of research, but I am unable to test.  Please try the following and give me some feedback regarding what works and what doesn't.

I am unclear about what `var1` and `var2` are.  Are they First Name and Last Name?  Are they 2 separate usernames?  If they are comma separated, why does your regex permit the vars to contain a comma?

The following method will assume that a non-empty string will be wrapped in parentheses and that the captured string is like "FirstName, LastName" as a single string.  (If it is not, then just explode on the comma after `trim()`ing the parentheses.)

Untested Code:  (require a match, but the entire substring is "optional")

```
$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->group('/v1', function () {
    $this->get('/profile/~:{params:\(?[^,]*,?[^)]*\)?}',function($request,$response,$args){
    //   required capture-^        ^^^-optional()-^^^
        if(strlen($name=$request->getAttribute('params'))){
            $greeting='Hello ',substr($name,1,-1);
        }else{
            $greeting='Hello';
        }
        $response->getBody()->write($greeting);
        return $response;
    })->setName('profile');
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: How it is applied to the slim route in the php code?

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo I have updated my answer with a blind stab at a solution.  Please test and offer your feedback.  I'll try to help as much as I can.

Comment: Hello, @mickmacusa thank you for your code works like a charm!